# How do i hide button in user profile

Tags: python, django

How do i hide edit profile button in my profile page from other users, i want only the profile owner to be able to access the edit profile button. When every other users view another user profile page, the edit profile button will not be displayed to other users but only to the owner of the profile. I attached an image for a clear explanation.

[image]

I tried this:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
   Edit Profile
{% endif %}
```

but did not hide the Edit Profile button. How can i do this using only template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will show and hide if user is authenticated or not. All authenticated users will see the button.

from the value you passed in the view for the profile username etc you condition would be.
if your views in veiws.py return `

```
def profile(request, username):
  profile_img = Profile.objects.filter(user__username=username)

  return render (request,'profile.html',{'profile_img':profile_img})
```

Then in your template your condition would be.

```
{% if request.user == profile_img.user %}
   Edit Profile
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your code hide the button from other users and the owner. I want to hide the button to only the other users but not the owner (login user).

Comment: [profile] is the example, how are you passing user data? Let me see your view ill edit the answer to suit your problem

Comment: I thought this doesn't have anything to do with views.py. I there no way I can hide a button from other users to see but only the owner of the account.

Comment: the return, what the function returns, and the qs

Comment: I'm not using views here, I just have a button in my template that I do not want other users to have access to. Check the attached image

Comment: i see the image. how are you getting the 100 posts, 200 followers etc ? for that specific user you are viewing.

Comment: def profile(request, username) :profile_img = Profile objects.filter (user__username =username) this is what I use in getting the image. As for 100 followers I inputted that manually I have not yet fix a view code for that.

Comment: then should compare user of the profile image which the object is called profile_img.

Comment: I do not understand, can you help with the use of code?

Comment: edited the above code. check .. the object from your qs is profile_img then compare logged in user with profile_img user

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean, can you make an example with a code?

Comment: I use the code and still have an issue. Edit profile button do not show when view others profile, and also it is not showing in owner profile.

Comment: if you got a git repo let me check your code. or edit and put you entire view and model on your question.

Comment: OK I will do that. I am having another problem here. I want to display my profile picture in every page, this work for me {{ request.user.profile.profile_pic}}. But the problem is that, if a user has not yet uploaded a profile picture I would want to add a display image icon manually. How can I add an image icon, then when a user uploaded a profile picture it will override the image icon.

Comment: add default picture in the model. you add path to the picture.  .... profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='pic_folder/None/no-img.png', verbose_name='productpic')

Comment: no-img will be your icon name. Dont forget to vote the answer

Comment: Default image do not display in template, after added the path  'static/images/pic.jpg'